# Invoke built-in Configure Error Output dialog

Tags: c#, ssis

I have custom SSIS component:

- which inherits from PipelineComponent
- with custom UI which implements
- IDtsComponentUI which has error output (as suggested here: [Using Error Outputs in a Data Flow Component In design-time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136009%28v=sql.105%29.aspx))

I can attach error output (red arrow) to next component in pipeline. But I can't set column error and truncation behaviour in design-time (RD_NotUsed for each column is set and disabled/gray).

I would like to show built-in Configure Error Output dialog for my component, so user can set error and truncation behaviour using dialog he/she is familiar with. Is it possible and how?